# Put main link bar on room pages in chat

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, user-interface, chat

The main link bar on the chat home page says:

> users  | rooms | search | faq

but when you're in a room, you don't have the `users` or `faq` link.

How about just making the main link bar in the room change to

```
 users  | more rooms | faq
```

Note that a specific room search is already in the secondary link bar, but we may want to have the general search still in the main bar, so then we'd have it like

```
 users  | more rooms | search | faq
```

Comment: This has been bugging me, too.

Comment: As space at the top is at a premium, this could be bottom right next to the "legal" link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure "users" is pivotal to this screen, but there is now a link to the FAQ down near the input box (intended to help also with syntax etc)